# shell script post commit hook that just does date > /tmp/post-commit.log nothing is written to log file

Tags: bash, shell, svn, apache-http-server, svn-server

I installed svn server with apache 2 on ubuntu 10

i have created a post-commit.sh with a single 2 lines of code

repository/hooks/post-commit.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
date > /tmp/post-commit.log
```

nothing is written to that file
can anyone assist please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.ref.reposhooks.post-commit.html):

> Name
>
> post-commit — Notification of a successful commit.
>
> Description
>
> The post-commit hook is run after the transaction is committed, and a new revision created. Most people use this hook to send out descriptive emails about the commit or to notify some other tool (such as an issue tracker) that a commit has happened. Some configurations also use this hook to trigger backup processes.
>
> **The output from, and exit value returned by the post-commit hook program are ignored.**

---

What you want is a [pre-commit hook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.ref.reposhooks.pre-commit.html) (kind of obvious once you think about those names):

> Name
>
> pre-commit — Notification just prior to commit completion.
>
> Description
>
> The pre-commit hook is run just before a commit transaction is promoted to a new revision. Typically, this hook is used to protect against commits that are disallowed due to content or location (for example, your site might require that all commits to a certain branch include a ticket number from the bug tracker, or that the incoming log message is non-empty).
>
> **If the pre-commit hook program returns a non-zero exit value, the commit is aborted, the commit transaction is removed, and anything printed to stderr is marshalled back to the client.**

---

Also, make sure to make the script file executable, and use the exact name `pre-commit` or `post-commit`, i.e. without file name extension!

Comment: @Jason Did you make it executable? `chmod +x repository/hooks/post-commit.sh`? Also, try removing the `.sh` file name extension, I'm not sure if it works with these.

Comment: correct had to remove the .sh

Comment: Re quote #1: The `post-commit` script itself does not output anything; the output made by `date` is redirected internally.

Comment: @grawity He redirects manually to a file. While `stdout` and `stderr` are probably discarded/redirected, I don't think this output is removed. Otherwise these scripts will have a hard time doing anything.

Answer (score 1):

Try renaming the script to `repository/hooks/post-commit`.  The should be no extension in the filename.  Read the `repository/hooks/post-commit.tmpl` file for more information (specifically the first paragraph which states:

> The post-commit hook is invoked after a commit.  Subversion runs this hook by invoking a program (script, executable, binary, etc.) named '**post-commit**'